# "TypeError: execve() arg 3 contains a non-string value" on running a submin generic hook

Tags: python, svn

I have installed submin and am able to create and configure subversion repositories.

I would like to configure submin to copy my subversion hooks when creating a repository.

Submin has a [Generic Hook mechanism](https://ssl.supermind.nl/collab/projects/submin/wiki/GenericHooks) but I have failed to get it working. There are several hook directories, the wiki does not tell me which hook directory to use.

I added a simple script to:

/var/lib/submin/hooks/repository-create/copy-hooks

& I set ownership as www-data. On creating a repository receive the error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/submin/hooks/common.py", line 24, in trigger_hook
    trigger_user_hook(event, **args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/submin/hooks/common.py", line 51, in trigger_user_hook
    p = Popen([hook], env=env)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
TypeError: execve() arg 3 contains a non-string value
```

So it looks like that I have triggered/created a user hook but with errors.

EDIT:
The code creates a dictionary:

```
env = dict([(key.upper(), value) for key, value in args.iteritems()
        if value])
```

which it passes to popen().
Where 'args' was created using:

```
trigger_hook('repository-create', admin_username=session_user,
        repositoryname=name, vcs_type=vcs_type)
```

Researching the 'arg 3' error & the most likely cause is that the 'env' dictionary contains non character strings and typically Unicode strings. Adding debug of the 'env'  just before the popen() and:

```
type: <type 'unicode'> value: new
type: <class 'submin.models.user.User'> value: admin
type: <type 'unicode'> value: svn
```

So I am passing a class and Unicode strings.
I am not sure how to convert the class value and the Unicode strings to character strings. How do I character stringify within the loop? Addressing the route cause would seem the better option but would be happy with a hack.

EDIT 2:
I agree, the passing of the class is what I thought.
Your code raises a syntax error however & my Python is not good enough to debug, debug quickly at least!

fyi The calling code calls two sets of hooks, the tool's hooks functions and the user hooks:

```
# Then execute all hooks
if event in hooks:
    for hook_fn in hooks[event]:
    hook_fn(**args)

    trigger_user_hook(event, **args)
```

So I need to change locally. 
The dictionary 'env' is constructed from 'args'.
The key is 'ADMIN_USERNAME', the class has a method _getName(self). I can see what to call(?) but am struggling with syntax.... 
Please provide the code.

EDIT 3
Thanks. Both your new fix & your original conversion loop within 'trigger-user-hook' convert the class to text. The code no longer complains but my script does not run.
My script works outside submin.
PS I cannot upvote as lack rep.

Comment: "The code creates a dictionary" - unclear if it's your or `submin`'s code. (I already found out it's `submin/hooks/common.py:trigger_user_hook`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding debug printing of `hook` to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/submin/hooks/common.py` right before the line 51 could shed light on what specifically is wrong with the "arg 3".

Update:

Here's the code in the POSIX version of `execve()` that processes `env` and gives the error (`Python-2.7.9/Modules/posixmodule.c:3248`; only showing relevant lines):

```
keys = PyMapping_Keys(env);
vals = PyMapping_Values(env);
<...>
for (pos = 0; pos < i; pos++) {
<...>
    key = PyList_GetItem(keys, pos);
    val = PyList_GetItem(vals, pos);
    <...>
    if (!PyArg_Parse(
                key,
                "s;execve() arg 3 contains a non-string key",
                &k) ||
        !PyArg_Parse(
            val,
            "s;execve() arg 3 contains a non-string value",
            &v))
    {
        goto fail_2;
    }
```

As [Parsing arguments and building values - C API docs](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/arg.html) says, `'s'` means **either `str` or `unicode`; `TypeError` is raised otherwize of if there are embedded `\0`s; if a `unicode` can't be converted using *the default encoding*, `UnicodeError` is raised instead.**

So, it actually chokes on `type: <class 'submin.models.user.User'> value: admin`.

Update2:

The offending value is created and passed in `submin-2.2.1/models/repository.py`. Here's the diff to fix this:

```
--- a/submin/models/repository.py
+++ b/submin/models/repository.py
@@ -78,7 +78,7 @@ class Repository(object):
    def add(vcs_type, name, session_user):
        vcs = models.vcs.get(vcs_type, "repository")
        vcs.add(name)
-       trigger_hook('repository-create', admin_username=session_user,
+       trigger_hook('repository-create', admin_username=unicode(session_user),
            repositoryname=name, vcs_type=vcs_type)

    def __init__(self, repositoryname, vcs_type):
```

I created a pull request to apply it into the official codebase: https://github.com/mjholtkamp/submin/pull/1

Comment: Thanks. Added debug code. Seems that I need to stringify() a class value and convert Unicode to string. At the limits of my Python!

Comment: See update. I need to change 'env' after creation or during creation. Your code gives a syntax error though.

Comment: Thanks. That removes the syntax & execve() error. The script does not seem to run however.

Comment: Thanks. Update removes errors but my script does not run.

Comment: Thanks again. My script did not run due to a permissions issue. Your answer works fine. Wish I could up vote or mark as closed!

Comment: The original error turned out to be an actual bug in `submin` so your question is completely valid. I'd be grateful if you reward me with some rep for my efforts by accepting the answer since it did address the issue.

Comment: As a side note, don't forget to remove the no-longer-needed debug printing statements from the library's code :-)